# [Flutter]How to keep the flexibleSpace of the SliverAppBar expanded when scrolling down in the NestedScrollView?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to keep the SliverAppBar expand when scroll down in the NestedScrollView?

I want to change the flag named '_locked' to lock the SliverAppBar height, but I don't know how to do that.

May be need to use the SliverPersistentHeader widget?

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final double expanded = 200;
  bool _locked = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final top = MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top;
    return Scaffold(
      body: NestedScrollView(
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
          return [
            SliverAppBar(
              pinned: true,
              floating: true,
              title: Text(widget.title),
              expandedHeight: expanded - top,
              flexibleSpace: LayoutBuilder(
                builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
                  return Container(height: expanded, color: Colors.red);
                },
              ),
            ),
          ];
        },
        body: ListView(
          children: ListTile.divideTiles(
              context: context,
              tiles: List.generate(
                  50,
                  (index) => ListTile(
                        title: Text('Index: $index'),
                      ))).toList(),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(_locked ? Icons.lock_open : Icons.lock_outline),
        onPressed: () {
          /// Switch the flag
          setState(() {
            _locked = !_locked;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to bind `_locked` to the [pinned](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliverAppBar/pinned.html) property of `SliverAppBar`.

A gif example is included in the docs I've linked!

Comment: 'keep expanded' it is mean when the CustomScrollView scrolling down alway to keep the SliverAppBar flexibleSpace expanded, not just let the appbar pinned at the top position.